# How can I incorporate a known measurement error per group into a GAM?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am trying to investigate surface changes using a time series of 3D point clouds. Due to data volume, I am segmenting the point cloud in small (eg. 50cmx50cm) areas and for each compute a generalized additive model (GAM) that models elevation data as a function of time and space. After accounting for time, slope and the measurement error, the resulting elevation data should be normally distributed.

I'd like to infer knowledge about whether and how the surface changed over time. Other ideas about how to approach this are very welcome, especially regarding computation time. I thought about using MARS, but did not find a way of incorporating a random error with a known distribution.

```
mod.gam <- gam(z ~ s(timestamp_num, bs='ad') + x + y, data = df)
```

The area of interest was surveyed every hour. Every survey has a measurement error, whose mean and variance can be estimated. How can I include this error?  I thought about including an `offset(error)` term in the model, but that does not seem to influence the standard error calculations. Then I was thinking of adding it as a random effect smoother that depends on the survey like this:

```
mod.gam <- gam(z ~ s(timestamp_num, bs='ad') + x + y +
                   s(error, survey, bs="re"), data = df)
```

Would that be an adequate approach? How can I specify the mean and variance of the random effect?

Comment: The ranef will only model a different mean per area. Are you really fitting a Gaussian model? If so, you could include a different variance per survey by fitting a location scale model wherein you model the mean and the variance using family `gaulss`, and include the ranef in the variance formula too.

Comment: Well after accounting for time, slope and the measurement error, the resulting elevation data should be normally distributed. Fitting a location scale model is too resource intensive. I'd like to model the elevation change over time for one area over time while respecting the uncertainty induced by the known measurement error. I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: You can't specify the variance of a random effect; it is inversely related to the smoothness parameter in the spline parameterisation of the random effect. This isn't quite true; you can set the single smoothness parameter to be some single value, but that doesn't help you. The *brms* package allows for measurement error models, which you might look at to see if it accommodates this issue (though the "resource intensive" bit probably preclude MCMC).

Comment: The `weights` argument can, I believe be used to effectively say that the variance of each observation is proportional to some value; if you can assume that the variance of an observation is proportional to the variance of the measurement error then passing in `meas_var / mean(meas_var)` to the `weights` argument (where `meas-var` is the measurement error variance) would try to account for the extra uncertainty. Beyond this, I don't think you can use *mgcv* for this. (Do look at `bam()` for computational efficiencies, it is as restricted as `gam()` for this measurement error problem though).